# Python:Reading data from file and printing them into a file based on a given template which can change

Tags: python, python-3.x

Iam very much new to this place and python programming,So I have to code a python program as below :

1.Multiple entries exists in student.txt file for different subject fields as Rollno, StudName, Subject, Marks for each student.

```
e.g

<Rollno>,<StudName>,<Marks>,<Subject> #not required to be in file

101,Santosh , maths, 35

102, Hina, English, 41

101,Santosh , Hindi, 30
```

2.Merge the student.txt data as per the template file (tempstud.txt) below for each student. The total for each student should be displayed below at end of record.

```
Template:
{Id:<Rollno>, Name:<StudName>,subject:<Subject>,marks:<Marks>}

e.g

Santosh.101.txt

{Id: 101,name:Santosh , Subject: maths, Marks:35}

{Id: 101,name:Santosh , Subject: Hindi, Marks:30}

Total Marks :65
3.Create different files for each student , filename of this output file should be <Name>.<rollno>.txt

Note:
Supposing I am changing the template file as below 

{ marks:<Marks>-Id#<Rollno>-Name:<StudName>-subject#<Subject>}

I can also make changes to data files as below(changing column fields )

<Subject>,<RollNo>,<StudName>,<Marks>
maths,101,Santosh , 35
English,102, Hina, , 41
Hindi, 101,Santosh , 30

Code should  be generic enough for above changes also.
```

I wrote the below code :

```
# variables used
List = []     # To hold the records of students
rolenum = []  # To hold all the rolenumbers
i = 0         #counter variable
#template
Template={}
# function to write into the file
def write(MyList, id=0):
    s = open(MyList[1] + "." + id + ".txt", 'a')
    s.writelines("Id: " + MyList[0] + " Name: " + MyList[1] + " Subject: " + MyList[2] + " Marks: " + MyList[3] + '\n')
    return (s, int(MyList[3])) # returns the file descriptor and the individual subject score

# Open the file to read the data into a List
with open('student.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tmp = line.strip().split(',')
        List.append(tmp)  # Contains all the student details

len = len(List)  # Total no. of Records

while i < len:
    if (List[i][0]) not in rolenum:
        rolenum.append(List[i][0])  # Finding all the Rolenumbers to use it as a key to individual student record
    i += 1
i = 0
temp_reader()
for val in rolenum:
    marks = 0 # variable to hold the Marks for the student
    while i < len:
        if val == List[i][0]:
            s, tmp = write(List[i], val)
            marks = marks + tmp

        i += 1
    s.write("\nTotal Marks is " + str(marks))   #Write the marks into the student file
    s.close()
    i = 0`enter code here`
#================================End of Code ===================================================#
```

The part of creating the files with student details and marks is done. but how will I code in such a way that it is generic to changes that are made to template file?